# loss function values between zero and one

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

Which loss function returns values only between zero and one? 
The question is regarding Loss for Binary Classification (using pytorch).
By trying those functions:

```
loss = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy(output, target)
```

and

```
loss_function = torch.nn.BCELoss()
loss = loss_function(output, target)
```

the return value sometimes was bigger than 1.

Comment: The values can be greater than 1 because it's a negative logarithm. You can use Mean Absolute Error (MAE) to give values between 0 and 1 for a sigmoid/softmax output.

Answer (score 0):

###### The loss function equation of BCE is:

for each x_i, y_i we messure:

> l_i =−w_i[y_i⋅log(x_i)+(1−y_i)⋅log(1−x_i)]

1. the default value of the BCE loss is the average of all the l_i's, you could change that by inputting `reduction='sum'` in the parameters of the BCE function.
2. notice that the output of the log function is in this range (-infinity, 0) which is multiplied with -w_i; w_i has a positive value during the training process.
   to sum up, the value of the loss function could be >1